# How do we use sonarqube on a different context root?

Tags: sonarqube

In previous versions of SonarQube we had a property that allowed setting the context root [`sonar.web.context`](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server#InstallingtheServer-installingWebServerInstallingtheWebServer) however after a recent update, this does not appear work anymore.  Is there an alternative method of performing this function?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like they have decided to just drop the capability on 5.4 https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7122

But may be reintroduced in 5.5 https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-7494 so I guess I had [downgraded Sonar to 5.3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/138284/how-to-downgrade-a-package-via-apt-get).  That way my [reverse-proxy-auth-sonar-plugin](https://github.com/trajano/reverse-proxy-auth-sonar-plugin) that I for my installation still functions correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can upgrade to 5.6.3 LTS http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading, the capability was included again from 5.5 on.